# FETCH API and Display Data

Tags: javascript, json, function, api, httprequest

I been try to get some research online regarding this task I am new to JS and API thing but I do know basic fetch on API. Can someone give me some good reference about this.

1.For each item, add a hyperlink to the item name that will trigger a JavaScript function when clicked.

2.In the JavaScript function, use an HTTP request to get the full details of the deal from the api /crm/v3/object/itemsample.

3.Once the details are obtained, redirect the user to a new page that displays the full details of the item, such as the item name, amount, and other properties.

I been expecting to redirect to a new page after click the hyperlink fetched from the API

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Identifying the target resource provider would be helpful as well. (Who is hosting the endpoint `/crm/v3/object/itemsample`)